# OnClickListener Overriding

Tags: android

I have defined button.setOnClicklistener in OnCreate callback of activity.

user clicks the button and when the task is completed(lets say fetch some data), program receives the response from server.

Now, program expects another click from the user to initiate a new task (lets say upload an image).

On the same button, how might I change the listener? Is there be a way to nullify the previous listener and add a new one?

**I don't want to define two buttons but change listener function (or override  of button as per the data being received from server**

Button.OnClickListener1 ---> completed task ---> New Button.OnClickListener

I know it can be done using flags, or setting text on button but how many times can we override an on click listener?

So question comes down to how many times can we override a function in an inheriting class and which one will be executed, if more than once.

Sorry if this is a noob question but just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 onClickListener instances, one that does the first task, one that does the second.  When you want to change behaviors, call setOnClickListener(secondListener).

This isn't a problem for inheritance, and generally you do not want to subclass a View for different behaviors like this.  You shouldn't mix UI code like a button with application logic like what a button is supposed to do when pressed, doing so makes a hard to maintain, confusing program.

Comment: Thanks Gabe , Making 2 instances sounds great . ill try that out